# "Auto" Width of my gridviewcolumn does not work in my listview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm

EDIT : It's ok now everything is fine. I did an "order by" to my list, and now Gridviewcolumn is auto. I don't know why, i don't know if it's a bug, but if i delete this "order by", it's buggy. If not, everything is fine. Good for me !

I have a listview that I fill with two columns. I would like the width of these two columns to be set to "auto", so as to fit the content.

Currently the problem is the following: When displayed, the content of my columns is cut off and horizontal bar isn't here, as if the "auto" setting was not interpreted (img1). However, if I change the Width in WPF while the application is running, and set auto again, it works perfectly (img2).

It's like the "auto" can't work at initialization. I'd like to know why, and if it's solvable?

img1 (load the page, auto doesn't work) :

[image]

img2 (when i change width to auto during the app running on VS2019) :

[image]

The Listview :

```
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListeAgentsEtablissementCourant}">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Supprimer}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader />
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock
                                            HorizontalAlignment="center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="center"
                                            FontSize="10"
                                            Text="{Binding Matricule}"
                                            FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader />
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock
                                            HorizontalAlignment="center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="center"
                                            Text="{Binding Nom}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: You probably have to check the parent container's layout behavior. What you describe is not the default behavior of the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now everything is fine. I did an "order by" to my list, and now Gridviewcolumn is auto. I don't know why, i don't know if it's a bug, but if i delete this "order by", it's buggy. If not, everything is fine. Good for me !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi GeffGeff, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)